# Are benefits available only to people with certain mental health conditions legal in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, discrimination

I work in the UK. Recently, my employer introduced benefits for people with certain medical conditions (including mental health problems)—i.e., only people suffering from the condition would receive the additional benefit.

Is this form of positive discrimination legal in the UK?

Comment: What sort of benefit is thgis. Is it something intended to help a person with such a condition deal with it? Or is it unrelated?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I'm guessing from context and OP's deliberate vagueness that this is about reasonable accomodations and OP wants their equal attention cake.